# What does "shopping" mean?

Tags: clash-of-clans, terminology

I'm playing Clash of Clans and someone said "shopping" when asking for troops, and then posted a replay with text "nice shopping trip" where their defense wins. Another use I've seen of this term by them is "somebody take these troops before I go shopping with them".

[image: "Shopping" and asking for troops]

[image: "somebody take these troops before I go shopping with them"]

[image: replay with text "nice shopping trip" where their defense wins]

What does "shopping" mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Shopping is a colloquial term for a raid/attack in Clash of Clans. Generally if they say it's a "nice shopping trip", then they either got a lot of the type of loot they were looking for, or just a lot of loot in general. So in the replay where his defense won, the attacker probably got a decent amount of loot from the attack, and "going shopping" would be attacking some one else for loot.

Note: I have not heard this used by many people, and most of the people I have heard use it are from the UK, so it is possible that it is a regional term to use instead of raiding/looting/farming/attacking.